# ili2118A touch driver issue

Tags: linux-kernel, sencha-touch, android-developer-api, bsp

Touch driver not responding after kernel boot

We are working here in Android 10 version for 7inch display with touch (chip ili2118a).
The ili251x touch driver we written, Touch IRQ is responding up-to kernel boot. After that the touch driver is not responding. But using the below command we verified the interrupt IRQ pin, The interrupt count is increasing

cat /proc/interrupts

we are getting IRQ pin name ili251x
Any one know the reason why we are not getting touch response after kernel boot. please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: With no information, no-one can help you.  Are you using the existing ili210x driver with modifications?  If not please show your code, how you disabled the built-in driver, and show how you know your driver is being called.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.